# Display a model objects as choices in Django Poll app choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I am working on an application where I am using the  [django poll app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) with another app name schoolbooks which have an app named schools. I have added a model in schoolbooks app i.e

```
schoolbooks/models.py
from polls.models import Question

class Schools(models.Model):
    name=models.CHarField(max_length=100)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    polls=models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

models in polls app

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have two polls or questions in Question model in polls/models.py:
**Which is the best school?**
**WHich school has best staff?**

and only with these two polls i want to show the list of schools as choices. I am using django poll app as an app and don't want to make any change in it.
I want to show the School model instances as the choices for these two polls and want people to enable voting for these polls.
like

```
Which is the best school?    
school1
school2
school3
```

Kindly suggest me a solution. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right: You could insert Data using the Django shell or write a little script. First you need all the schools that you want as option (e.g. via the admin interface). Than you open the Django shell and create a question with question_text = "Which is the best school?". Then you can loop through the schools and for each school you create a Choice with the schoolname as choice_text.

EDIT - I just saw, that you have a m2m Field in your School-Model. For my solution you don't need that.

Comment: I think i will have to create another model to sore the number_of_votes and school name with the question. something like 
`class Votes(models.Model):
    votes=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    question=models.ForeignKey(Question)
    school=models.ForeignKey(School)`
and when someone vote it will create an instance of this model. if previously exists then will only increase the number of votes field . i think

Comment: You could also add a foreign key to the Choice class that links to school. That would be the easiest solution I quess.

Comment: But the restriction is i can't make any change in the poll app. whatever i have to do is to do within the schoolbooks app.or i think what i can do is whenever i create a school it should also be stored in the choices. means in save method i can create two choice instances which relates to these both questions or polls. am i right?